# Pass partial output of a function to another function as an argument?

Tags: python, function

I've been struggling with this for a bit now and could use some guidance.  In principal, what I'm trying to do is simple.  I have 3 functions, including a `main()`.

The first function returns 3 outputs (all dictionaries), which I am then calling in main.  In main, I'm simply printing the output I need by providing the dictionary name and index.

My second function needs to take the last returned output from the first function as its only argument.  This function then needs to store the key name and the count of times this key appears in the dictionary produced by the first function as another dictionary.

So pseudo code would look something like this:

```
fcn a(x,y,z)  
  return x,y,z

fcn b(a(x))  
  c = {key: count(key)}  
  return c

fcn main()  
  print(a(x))  
  print(c)
```

Hope this makes sense.  I did find some help for passing functions as parameters in other functions, but can't quite make sense of passing actual output of one function to another function.

Comment: Protip: when you're writing code in Stack Overflow, indent it by four spaces; that'll format it in a monospace font and preserve all the indentation.

Comment: Thanks Adam.  Obviously, I'm still learning my way around Stack Overflow.  I'll keep an eye on that in future posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your function returns, you can assign its output to variables, like this:

```
x_out, y_out, z_out = a(x, y, z)
```

Then, just pass whichever variables you want into a second function:

```
b(x_out)
```

---

The reason it's not working the way you'd expect, is when you're returning more than one thing from a function in Python, you're actually returning a thing called a 'tuple'. So, given the following code:

```
def a(x, y, z):
    return x, y, z

foo = a(1, 2, 3)
```

the value of `foo` is `(1, 2, 3)`; a tuple containing the value `1` in the first position, `2` in the second position and `3` in the third.

If you call a second function with the result of the first, like this:

```
def b(input):
    print(type(input), repr(input))

b(a(1, 2, 3))
```

you'll see that `input` is a tuple containing all three values.

Comment: This makes sense.  I'm looking forward to trying this when I get home.  I'll post an update then.  Thanks Adam.

Comment: @Ryan If you are learning python, then use the debugger more... Inspect objects during runs with breakpoints. You will see data types and structure more clearly. Good luck and enjoy Python.